# PHP MYSQL display sql results with foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a list of submitted vehicle checks. The checks are organized and grouped by date. The table shows the date as well as who submitted that check. When I click view, it should show all the checks, status of checks, and comments for submitted checks for that date only.

I have the table set up as form, that when "view" is clicked, it acts as a submit button to POST to another php file to display that dates checks.

[image: This is the first table]
This shows the table where the submitted checks are listed out by date.

```
$checkssql = " SELECT * FROM $appname2 GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC";
$checksqry = mysqli_query($conn, $checkssql);

<form name="submittedchecks" id="submittedchecks" method="POST" action="view-submitted-check.php">
   <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">   
      <table class="table" >
         <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Submitted By</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody class="table-border-bottom-0">
            <?php while ($checks = mysqli_fetch_array($checksqry)) {{
            echo '<input type=hidden name="checkdate[]" value='. $checks['date']. '>';
            echo '<input type="text" name="appname" id="appname" readonly value="'.$appname2.'" hidden="hidden">';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td> <input type="text" value="'.$checks['date'].'" name="date[]" id="date" style="border: none" readonly></td>';
            echo '<td>'.$checks['submitted_by'].'</td>';
            echo "<td> <button class='btn btn-info' type='submit' name='submitview' id='submitview'>View</button> </td> " ;}
            if($row['user_type']=='admin'){  echo "<td> <a href=delete-truck-check-script.php?id=".$checks['id']."><button class='btn btn-danger' type='button' >Delete Check</button></a> </td> " ;} 
echo'</tr>'; }?>
      </table>
   </div>
</form>
```

This is the code for getting the post data and displaying it in the table of the selected date of the check.

```
foreach ($_POST['checkdate'] as $index => $id){ 
    
$appname = $_POST['appname'];
$date = $_POST['date'][$index];
    
$viewlog = "SELECT * FROM $appname WHERE date = '$date' ORDER BY id";
$viewresult = mysqli_query($conn, $viewlog);
     
 }

<table class="table" >
   <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Check Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Comment</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="table-border-bottom-0">
      <?php while ($checkview = mysqli_fetch_array($viewresult)) {{
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>' .$checkview['check_name']. '</td>';
      if($checkview['status']=='Pass'){  echo "<td> <label class='btn rounded-pill btn-outline-success'>Pass</label> </td> " ;} 
      if($checkview['status']=='Warning'){  echo "<td> <label class='btn rounded-pill btn-outline-warning'>Warning</label> </td> " ;}
      if($checkview['status']=='Fail'){  echo "<td> <label class='btn rounded-pill btn-outline-danger'>Fail</label> </td> " ;}
      echo '<td>' .$checkview['comment']. '</td>';}
      echo'</tr>'; }?>
</table>
```

Ive tried multiple answers from other posts and nothing is working. I need another set of eyes to find my error.

I switched $id to $index, but its getting only 1 date.
I clicked on the top check "03-21-2024", but its showing the check for "03-20-2024"

[image: As you can see here]

[image: My DB table]

Comment: Your first code block creates invalid HTML. The first two `<input>` elements are not inside `<tr>` and `<td>`.

Comment: `$_POST['date'][$id]` should be `$_POST['date'][$index]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even if [you are escaping variables, its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string%5D)! You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating variables into the query.

Comment: Do you really need a submit button in each row of the table? Also, IDs should be unique, you shouldn't use the same ID in all the table rows. Are you sure you even need IDs on those elements?

Comment: The first 2 inputs are hidden and dont need to be in a row. I was using them just for POST only. The id's can be deleted as they serve no purpose, I just use them to keep track of things. When I use $index I get no errors, but its showing the date as the same for both checks, which in turn only shows 1 date of checks no matter which date is clicked.

Comment: I revised my OP so you can see the updates and results

Comment: You need to put everything inside the `foreach` loop. Otherwise you're just using the value of `$viewresult` from the last row of the table.

Comment: I put everything in the foreach loop. It is now showing every single check regardless of date. Error: Undefined Variable $date

Comment: What is the `checkdate` input for? You never use `$id` in the code.

Comment: Why do you need the `appname` input in every row? They all have the same value.

Comment: Its a code for another, but extremely similar, solution created by @KenLee from another post that worked very well. Its somewhat working for this as well, but the dates are acting the same. and no matter what date is clicked, its pulling checks from the same date no matter what.

Comment: "nothing is working" is not a great expression of the error that you are experiencing.

Comment: There must be no sch tables in the database. But only one table, where whatever "2" is just a column and used in WHERE clause.

Comment: I remember when I didn't use a framework to write web applications, like 15 years ago. Those were dark times. Why do this to yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're only interested in one specific date, you shouldn't put an array of inputs in the form. Instead, there should be a separate form in each row. The form can be entirely inside the `<td>` with the submit button, it just contains the `appname` hidden input, and the date can be in the value of the submit button.

```
$checkssql = " SELECT * FROM $appname2 GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC";
$checksqry = mysqli_query($conn, $checkssql);
?>
<div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">   
  <table class="table" >
     <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Submitted By</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody class="table-border-bottom-0">
        <?php while ($checks = mysqli_fetch_array($checksqry)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<input type=hidden name="checkdate[]" value='. $checks['date']. '>';
            echo '<input type="text" name="appname" id="appname" readonly value="'.$appname2.'" hidden="hidden">';
            echo '<td>'.$checks['date'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$checks['submitted_by'].'</td>';
            echo "<td> <form method='post' action='view-submitted-check.php'><input type='hidden' name='appname' value='".$appname2.".><button class='btn btn-info' type='submit' name='submitview' value='".$checks['date']."'>View</button></form> </td> " ;
            if($row['user_type']=='admin'){  echo "<td> <a href=delete-truck-check-script.php?id=".$checks['id']."><button class='btn btn-danger' type='button' name='delete' value='".$checks['date']."'>Delete Check</button></a> </td> " ;} 
            echo'</tr>';
        }?>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Then when processing the form submission, you don't have to loop over the parameters. There will just be one `$_POST['submitview']` containing the date of the row they clicked on.

```
<?php
$appname = $_POST['appname'];
if (!valid_appname($appname)) {
    die("Invalid appname");
}

$date = $_POST'submitview'];
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM $appname WHERE date = ? ORDER BY id");
mysql_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $date);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$viewresult = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
?>
<table class="table" >
   <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Check Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Comment</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="table-border-bottom-0">
      <?php while ($checkview = mysqli_fetch_array($viewresult)) {
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>' .$checkview['check_name']. '</td>';
          if($checkview['status']=='Pass'){  echo "<td> <label class='btn rounded-pill btn-outline-success'>Pass</label> </td> " ;} 
          elseif($checkview['status']=='Warning'){  echo "<td> <label class='btn rounded-pill btn-outline-warning'>Warning</label> </td> " ;}
          elseif($checkview['status']=='Fail'){  echo "<td> <label class='btn rounded-pill btn-outline-danger'>Fail</label> </td> " ;}
          echo '<td>' .$checkview['comment']. '</td>';
          echo'</tr>';
       }
      ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```